# Why no Task.Run overload that accepts a task?

Tags: c#

I find myself repeatedly doing:

```
var task = f(); // some code returning a task

Task.Run(async () => await task);
```

Which is to me confusing code that I often stumble on.
Is there a reason *why* the `Task` class does not have overload that accepts a task ?

ie,

```
public static Task Run(Task task) => Task.Run(async () => await task);
```

?

Comment: Why not just `await f();`?

Comment: because that way the code calling Task.Run is not async and does not need to await Task.Run .. I admit I may be confused here :(

Comment: You are awating a task with Task.Run because you do **not** want to await that task? - Remove that Task.Run line and thats it

Comment: If you are repeatedly doing that, you are doing things *very* wrong.

Comment: Have you considered to use Wait or Resul? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Wait_System_TimeSpan_ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a reason why the Task class does not have a `Run` overload that accepts a task ?

Yes, because there shouldn't be one.

For the sake of this answer, a `Task` or `Task<T>` represents some operation that does some work and returns a value that *may or may not exist yet*. It's an abstraction over all kinds of work (e.g. a concurrent operation running on another thread, an asynchronous IO operation running elsewhere in hardware, a representation of a synchronous operation, or something else.

What a `Task`/`Task<T>` does **not** represent is a `Func<>` or `Action<>` nor does it represent a "job template" that you can use to start a new operation (think of it as representing a job that's already begin).

As for `Task.Run` specifically: the real `Task.Run(Func<>)`/`Task.Run(Action)` method in .NET is shorthand for **starting** a `Func<>` or `Action<>` in the default scheduler's thread-pool (i.e. concurrently, multi-threaded). You cannot "restart" a `Task` (a `Task`'s state-machine graph is strictly unidirectional), you can only start a new `Task` using whatever mechanism was used to start the original `Task`. So you cannot arbitrarily restart an asynchronous `Socket` operation, for example, because that would mean rewinding your entire program's state, and that means breaking the laws of physics...

If you have a `Task<T>` object, then (assuming you're using it correctly) whatever operation it represents will have already been scheduled or otherwise started - or be already completed - therefore you cannot "start" a `Task` by passing it to `Task.Run` because it has already been started (this is an oversimplification).

---

The example you gave (reposted below) doesn't do anything useful:

```
public static Task Run(Task task) => Task.Run(async () => await task);
```

I've rewritten it in long-form below to make it easier to follow:

```
public static Task Run(Task originalTask)
{
    LambdaCapture capture = new LambdaCapture( originalTask );
    Task poolTask = Run( capture.Run ); // Remember that a Delegate includes the `this` reference unlike a raw C-style function-pointer.
    return poolTask;
}

// Oversimplified representation of what Task.Run does:
public static Task Run( Action action )
{
    ThreadPool pool = GetThreadPoolFromSomewhere();

    TaskCompletionSource tsc = new TaskCompletionSource();

    Action wrappedAction = () =>
    {
        // Run the action:
        action();

        // When it completes, inform TaskCompletionSource:
        tsc.SetResult(); // Task (not `Task<T>`) has no result value.

        // When `SetResult()` is invoked, the thread running this code will not return to here until after it runs the contination scheduled after `originalTask`.
    };

    pool.AddJob( wrappedAction ); // Adds `wrappedAction` to a queue which is dequeued by the first available thread.

    return tsc.Task; // <-- this is a new Task created by the TaskCompletionSource.
}

private class LambdaCapture
{
    private readonly Task originalTask;

    public Runnable( Task originalTask )
    {
        this.originalTask = originalTask;
    }

    public async Task Run()
    {
         await this.originalTask;
    }
}
```

When your proposed `Task.Run(Task)` method is invoked, it does this:

1. It will schedule `LambdaCapture.Run` to run on the first available thread in the thread-pool.
2. It will then create and return a separate new `Task` instance to represent the thread-pool operation (i.e. the concurrent operation) regardless of the nature of `originalTask`.
3. When the thread-pool becomes available and a worker thread runs `LambdaCapture.Run`, it will <sub>(oversimplification warning)</sub> check to see if `originalTask` is completed, and if so, will return and inform `originalTask`'s scheduler that it completed, if not it will schedule the rest of `Runnable.Run` (i.e. all of the code after the `await` - which is just a single `return;` statement in this case) to run after `originalTask` completes by making it a *continuation*.
4. So when `originalTask` does complete (assuming it *does* complete) then the thread that is assigned the next continuation from `originalTask` will then run the rest of the `Task.Run` operation and inform the worker-thread pool scheduler that it's done, and then (presumably) execute the contination of the `await` from whatever code `awaits` the `Task` returned from `Task.Run`.

   - If this is confusing, it's because I suck at explaining it. `Task<T>` in C# works essentially the same way as `Promise<T>` in JavaScript/TypeScript or `std::promise` in C++.

In short: there is no reason to do what you're proposing, other than to waste CPU cycles in a thread-pool thread. As @Fabio says, just do `await task` in the original method.

If you can't `await task` in your original method because that method isn't an `async` method then even if `Task.Run(Task)` existed it wouldn't help because you *still* need to `await` the `Task` that is returned by `Task.Run`.

Comment: thanks ! that is very helpful, I was using it in cases where I created a task with `new Task(() => {...}` to be stored in my "scheduler" and started later

Comment: @kofifus Never use `new Task`! What are you creating new `Task` objects for? You should only ever use `TaskCompletionSource`.

Comment: @kofifus I do admit that `Task` has a bad API design - it stems from `Task`'s original purpose as representing _only_ concurrent operations in the Task Parallel Library (TPL), it was repurposed for representing truly asynchronous operations (which are not necessarily concurrent or multi-threaded!) a couple of years later. The `new Task(Action)` constructor is only meant for use with TPL, and not for asynchronous operations.

Comment: Thanks ! I have tasks which are produced in one place but can only be started later so I store them and then run them later. "You should only ever use TaskCompletionSource" I guess we're getting off topic but any helpful reference on that ?

Comment: Another example: I inherit `BackgroundService` for my window service then AFASIK _have_ to do `protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) { await Task.Run(() => MySyncCode(cancellationToken)); }`

Comment: sorry for multiple comments - "you still need to await the Task that is returned by Task.Run" I don't believe that is true, the task us queued for running by Task.Run ?

Comment: If you don’t `await` it you may miss out on unhandled exceptions or not be accurately notified of results.